# AFHTTPRequestOperation restore progress bar when view closed and reopened?

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, afnetworking, nsoperation

I am currently stuck on a problem with my app and how I can restore an active UIProgressView within a UICollectionViewCell after the user exits the view controller by clicking Back and then going back into it.

AFHTTPRequestOperation is still running in the background downloading the file when the user exits the view, however upon return it just looks like the download is not happening and the UIProgressView is back to 0.

This is the code i am running after clicking download on the Collection View cell which works fine but only for the life time of the view.

```
 [operation1 setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
        NSLog(@"Progress = %f", (float)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead );
        float progressValue = (float)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead;
        [cell.downloadProgress setProgress:progressValue];

    }];

    [operation1 start];
```

Any tips on how I can restore this download state / progress on the collection view when it is re loaded?

Thanks Aaron

Answer (score 1):

This is probably also not working if you scroll way down and back up your collection view.  The issue is that `cell` only points to the correct cell until it's scrolled off screen (it might be reused for different content, or might be `nil` later).

The operation should tell the controller the progress, instead of the cell.

One possible implementation could look like this:

```
__weak typeof(operation1)weakOperation = operation1;
[operation1 setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    __strong __typeof(weakOperation)strongOperation = weakOperation;
    NSLog(@"Progress = %f", (float)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead );
    float progressValue = (float)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead;
    [self updateProgress:progressValue forOperation:strongOperation];
}];

[operation1 start];
```

And the method in your controller could look like this:

```
- (void) updateProgress:(float)progress forOperation:(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)operation {
    YourCustomCollectionViewCell *cell = // find the correct cell using 'operation', and your data model
    [cell.downloadProgress setProgress:progress];
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply I was referencing IndexPath so it only appeared once when you scrolled, your solution looks good and I was thinking along these lines but cannot work out how I find the correct sell using operation?  I will do some more reading up. Thanks again

Comment: You could keep references to all the operations in your data model, or you could try to figure out which cell is correct based on the url (look at `operation.request`).  The correct approach just depends on what you're doing specifically.

Comment: Thanks, looking further at the code the updateProgress method still runs when the view is closed and references the old IndexPath so I guess I need to figure out how to pass the correct cell / IndexPath when the view opens again.

Comment: Is the index path always the same?  If not, what does it depend on?

Comment: Yes the IndexPath changes what I am doing as a basic test in collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath if indexPath.row = 0 I'm storing the IndexPath in a property _downloadingIndexPath = indexPath; and that is used in updateProgress which works fine until the view is closed and opened again it seems the IndexPath is changed and the operation is not getting the latest _downloadingIndexPath value.  Thanks again